# Python with mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, levenshtein-distance

I am very beginner to python.

I have two tables named as Table A and Table B, In Table A have 1M record is available and Table B have 14M records is available and each record is a very big sentence(Paragraph) with special character numbers etc..,

I want to split the sentences into words of each record and compare the each row of Table A Column 1 into each and row of the Table B column 1 and I would like to the find top 5 highest match(Most relevant match) from the Table B record.

And, if I compare like 1M*14M it tooks more time could you please suggest any one the right way to do in python with mongodb

Comment: This is a fair number of questions squeezed into one. What have you done so far (i.e. accessing the data)? How does your code look like?

Comment: I have not coded yet, before am going to proceed i would like to know the way to do.

Comment: This is NOT trivial for a beginner. You should start by reading the respective manuals and coding simple examples yourself. Install yourself a test-bench / test system with mongodb, Python and pymongo so you can actually see & learn how your examples behave.